# Convert Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS to server

Tags: server

I'm trying to convert Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS running on my ODROID U3 to Ubuntu server.
After looking around, I've found the way to do it would be by running

```
apt-get update
tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
```

However, when I'm running these I get

```
root@odroid:/home/odroid# tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
tasksel: apt-get failed (100)
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you running from a console/tty? or from a terminal window?

Comment: It is almost certainly easier and faster to do a fresh install rather then remove all the desktop packages.

Comment: I'm running through putty ssh. There's no server installation available yet for this particular odroid model.

Comment: I'd just reinstall

Comment: You could try to use apt-get in place of tasksel. Also, are you sure ubuntu-desktop is installed? It depends on Unity, which wouldn't work on U3. I thought it was released with mate-desktop, and the [file names](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:u3_ubuntu_release_note_20160921) imply as much. Also, for those unaware, Odroid u3 is an ARM based board by [hardkernel](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/main.php). There is no was to install the server image, since none exists.